# How can I get the DOI of a paper from its title?

Tags: citations, tools, reference-managers, doi

Is there a way to get the DOI (Document Object Identifier) of a research paper when its title is available?

I am preparing a reference database I could not get the URL of all the references. So, I tried to search online but could not  get to anything. I will appreciate if anyone uses such tool/website or has any idea.

**EDIT**
I am sorry but my problem is little bigger. I need to automatically (not manually) get them from the websites. Of course, I do not want to do it for more than 50 papers if that is legal/allowed.

Comment: solutions can be found on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9711539/199217) and [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1768/452). And its fit on this site has been addressed on [meta.academia.se](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/97/258)

Comment: By the way, unfortunately you should expect that no technique will be completely reliable, which is why we need DOIs in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Reposted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711539/reverse-lookup-digital-object-identifier-given-table-of-citations/9795971#9795971):

> ### Here are three options
>
> #### CSV upload to [crossref.org](http://www.crossref.org)
>
> CrossRef allows you to upload the linked csv directly, and then
>   performs a text query here: http://www.crossref.org/stqUpload/
>
> However, only 18 of the 250 queries (~7%) returned a doi.
>
> #### XML Query
>
> Based on the [answer on SO by Brian
>   Diggs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711893/199217), here an attempt
>   that does 95% of the work - toward writing the xml-based query, it
>   still has a few bugs that require some deletion using `sed`. But the
>   biggest problem that my "session timed out" when the query was
>   submitted.
>
> the xml syntax includes an option to use fuzzy matching.
>
> the doiquery.xml contains the template text in @Brians answer; the
>   citations.csv is linked above. (using R, a sample csv can be found on
>   I have posted the first few lines of the table on [google
>   docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGN0VGxCd2NsNk5aQ0puUGlQZGczRkE&output=html),
>   or the [csv
>   version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGN0VGxCd2NsNk5aQ0puUGlQZGczRkE&output=csv)
>   (not all records have a doi))
>
> ```
> library(XML)
> doiquery.xml <- xmlTreeParse('doiquery.xml')
>
> query <- doiquery.xml$doc$children$query_batch[["body"]]
>
> citations <- read.csv("citations.csv")
>
> new.query <- function(citation, query = query){
>   xmlValue(query[["author"]]) <- as.character(citation$author)
>   xmlValue(query[["year"]]) <- as.character(citation$year)
>   xmlValue(query[["article_title"]][["text"]]) <- citation$title
>   xmlValue(query[["journal_title"]]) <- citation$journal
>   return(query)
> }
>
>
> for (i in 1:nrow(citations)){
>   q <- addChildren(q, add.query(citations[i,]))
> }
> axml <- addChildren(doiquery.xml$doc$children$query_batch, q )
>
> saveXML(axml, file = 'foo.xml')
> ```
>
> ### CSV to XML Converter
>
> Creativyst software provides a web based [CSV to
>   XML](http://www.creativyst.com/cgi-bin/Prod/15/eg/csv2xml.pl)
>   converter.
>
> Steps:
>
> 1. Enter columnames in ElementID's field,
> 2. "document" in DocID field
> 3. "query" in RowID field
> 4. Copy / paste csv in "Input CSV file".
> 5. Click Convert
>
> Also, see this related question:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880808/shell-script-to-parse-csv-to-an-xml-query

Comment: This [crossref page](https://apps.crossref.org/SimpleTextQuery) allows to directly input text query instead of uploading filey. To check for only a few papers, this is convenient.

Answer (score 4):

So you can do this easily using e.g. Web of Science, and probably other bibliographic databases available through your library.

If that isn't an option, a little google search lead me to the [DOI website FAQ](http://www.doi.org/faq.html), and question 3 is yours. There are 8  registration agencies for DOI, and no single way to search across DOI using document metadata. I tested the free [crossref service](http://www.crossref.org/guestquery/) and it was unable to find one of my articles because that journal doesn't use the crossref agency. One of the other agencies has that information, but you might have to search all of them to find it.

Finally, I tried Google Scholar, which will work if the article in question has reference information available online. That depends on the publisher.

Comment: I also had the same problem with crossref that I tried before posting  this question

Comment: I think Papers or Mendeley mentioned by @aeismail are the way to go - they claim to collect metadata automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The `R` package [fulltext](https://github.com/ropensci/fulltext) allows you to search DOI's given a title:

```
library(fulltext)
res1 <- ft_search(query = "Estimating Summer Nutrient Concentrations in
        Northeastern Lakes from SPARROW", from = "plos")
res1 <- ft_links(res1)
res1$plos$ids
```

> [1] "10.1371/journal.pone.0081457" "10.1371/journal.pone.0030492" "10.1371/journal.pone.0049220"

Answer (score 2):

Resources like [Web of Knowledge](http://www.isiknowledge.com) should have information on the DOI's for any titles that have them available (which should be "all of them" for anything that's been published in the last few years).

Tools like [Papers](http://www.mekentosj.com) or [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com) should also be able to "harvest" DOI's for published papers.

Comment: In response to your edit: both Papers and Mendeley should be able to retrieve the metadata for you using the title, unless the paper has just been released (as it might take a while to be archived by various search engines).

Comment: I tried but with no success. I will be grateful if you or someone can tell me a website where we can also fetch/download  the link to the documents/references. I will do my search again and not use the existing reference file

Answer (score 1):

Easier, code-free:

At this time, on the [CrossRef homepage](http://www.crossref.org/), there is a text-input field "Metadata search". It says:

> Search CrossRef's database of 71 million records for authors, titles,
>   DOIs, ORCIDs, ISSNs, FundRefs, license URIs, etc. You can even paste
>   entire references into the search box and discover their DOIs.

I have tried it out only for one DOI of which I happen to know that a record exists in the crossref database.

You can also use the [CrossRef search site](http://search.crossref.org) and paste the title of the paper there.

Answer (score 0):

Update in 2022: Easiest for me was using the website, where you can just copy and paste your references: https://search.crossref.org/references

I also looked at a few python libraries to interact with the crossref REST API, e.g.,

https://pypi.org/project/habanero/

https://gitlab.com/crossref/crossref_commons_py

The libraries were easy to use in general, but it was not straight forward how to get the DOI based on a title and there were not really any good examples for this task.

Answer (score 0):

As J. Schneider [mentions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/185526/158250), you can use "works" field query from crossref api. ([take a look at Richard Feynman example](https://api.crossref.org/swagger-ui/index.html#/Works/get_works)). It returns a JSON file. You can extract DOI from it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the author of [pysotsog](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pysotsog) I am recommending that library. It searches wikidata at this time and will use other bibliographic databases such as crossref, dblp, library catalogs and so on in the future it's intended to use general search engines as well. The concept is to be a specific search engine for scientific content see [sotsog search strategy](https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Pysotsog#Search_strategy).

Here is a command line example for the title "We Need a Magna Carta for the Internet" by Tim Berners-Lee with the DOI doi=10.1111/NPQU.11475.

```
sotsog We Need a Magna Carta for the Internet
We Need a Magna Carta for the Internet(Q55693402):✅
Paper ➞ We Need a Magna Carta for the Internet:
  wikiDataId=http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q55693402
  doi=10.1111/NPQU.11475
  publication_date=2014-07-01 00:00:00
opening https://scholia.toolforge.org/work/Q55693402 in browser
```

There is also a demo available at http://sotsog.bitplan.com
[image: Screenshot] which points to the [scholia page](https://scholia.toolforge.org/work/Q55693402) of the relevant article.

In simple cases like the one above you can directly search wikidata and use the [wikibase-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wikibase-cli) command line tools for it by searching for the [DOI](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P356) property.

First step - find the paper wikidata entry with a full text search

```
wd search We Need a Magna Carta for the Internet
Q55693402  We Need a Magna Carta for the Internet
```

Query  the DOI

```
wd query -s Q55693402 -p P356
10.1111/NPQU.11475
```